# Calculating "element-wise" the angles between two lists of vectors

Tags: python, optimization, numpy, computational-geometry

Let's say you have two lists of vectors:

```
v1s = [a, b, c]
```

```
v2s = [d, e, f]
```

I am interested in generating the following result:

> ```
> angles = [angleBetween(a, d), angleBetween(b, e), angleBetween(c, f)]
> ```

Here is my function to do this (it uses vector dot products in order to calculate the angles):

```
import numpy as np

def findAnglesBetweenTwoVectors(v1s, v2s):
    dot_v1_v2 = np.einsum('ij,ij->i', v1s, v2s)
    dot_v1_v1 = np.einsum('ij,ij->i', v1s, v1s)
    dot_v2_v2 = np.einsum('ij,ij->i', v2s, v2s)

    return np.arccos(dot_v1_v2/(np.sqrt(dot_v1_v1)*np.sqrt(dot_v2_v2)))
```

I call this function a lot, so optimizing it would be very helpful for me.  Is this possible?

Comment: Is the middle term `angleBetween(b, d)` or `angleBetween(b, e)`?

Comment: @hpaulj It should be `angleBetween(b, e)`! Fixed now.

Comment: You can spare yourself half of your square roots, which are expensive operations, by multiplying **before** taking the root, i.e. `return np.arccos(dot_v1_v2/np.sqrt(dot_v1_v1*dot_v2_v2))`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a way of packing the calculation into on call to `einsum`.

```
def findAnglesBetweenTwoVectors1(v1s, v2s):
    dot = np.einsum('ijk,ijk->ij',[v1s,v1s,v2s],[v2s,v1s,v2s])
    return np.arccos(dot[0,:]/(np.sqrt(dot[1,:])*np.sqrt(dot[2,:])))
```

for random vectors of length 10, the speed for this function and yours is basically the same.  But with 10000, (corrected times)

```
In [62]: timeit findAnglesBetweenTwoVectors0(v1s,v2s)
100 loops, best of 3: 2.26 ms per loop

In [63]: timeit findAnglesBetweenTwoVectors1(v1s,v2s)
100 loops, best of 3: 4.24 ms per loop
```

Yours is clearly faster.

We could try to figure out why the more complex `einsum` is slower (assuming the issue is there rather than the indexing in the last line).  But this result is consistent with other `einsum` testing that I've seen and done.  `einsum` on simple 2D cases is as fast as `np.dot`, and in some cases faster.  But in more complex cases (3 or more indexes) it is slower than the equivalent constructed from multiple calls to `np.dot` or `einsum`.

---

I tried tried factoring out the array construction, and got a speed improvement.

```
In [12]: V1=np.array(v1s)  # shape (3,10000,3)
In [13]: V2=np.array(v2s)
In [22]: timeit findAnglesBetweenTwoVectors2(V1,V2)
100 loops, best of 3: 2.63 ms per loop
```

---

I've corrected the times, using `v1s.shape==(10000,3)`

Comment: Pretty interesting. I am setting up things on a new computer where I will do my testing, so I hadn't gotten to testing that out yet myself. I can now cross it off of my list. My next idea was to perhaps execute the three `einsum` in parallel using `multiprocessing.pool`. I will get back to you with my results from that experiment.

Comment: I am also considering stealing [this code here](https://github.com/SimTk/openmm/blob/master/platforms/opencl/src/kernels/customCompoundBond.cl) (there is a function to compute the angle between two vectors), and using PyOpenCL to then implement it. Not sure though.

Comment: Update on the `multiprocessing` test: its *much* slower: the normal version is over 9000 (serious, no pun intended) times faster.

Comment: By the way, in my current construction, I am always supplying `numpy array` objects to the function. The shape should be (10000,).

Comment: I changed the inputs so the shape is correct.  The 3 `einsum` calculations is still better, though most of the extra in the single `einsum` case is due to the work of assembling the 3d arrays.